# Visual Studio Javascript files always marked as [dynamic] when breaking in debug

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging

Somehow this has changed.
I used to be able to set a breakpoint in a Javascript file and edit the file when it broke.
Even though edit-continue is not supported in Javascript at least you could restart or refresh the page to continue after editing. Now it is always opening a new tab with the readonly [dynamic] as pictured below.
So it's like the files have lost the mapping from IIS.

[image]

Comment: are these being served through a bundle config? are they minified? which browser are you trying to debug from? there are way too many missing pieces here.

Comment: Absolutely not minified. Just straight served up script tags